# Setup for a DNS Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, active-directory

Our DNS is being hosted by someone at the State Department of Education. They told me to just set up the DNS with forwarders. Do I also need to set up a forward lookup zone? Our goal is use this with Active Directory.

My Active Directory domain already exists and it is on this same server. I was told that they would just host the DNS and it had to be forwarded to them. I assume that we have to host our own zone.

Comment: Your question lacks some pretty significant details. Is it the case that they are hosting the AD DNS zone for your AD domain or are you looking to host your own AD DNS zone? Does the AD domain already exists? If so, where?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If they are hosting your DNS then you should not create any zones, because you should not be running a DNS server. All you should do is set all of your hosts' primary dns entries to the ip address of the server at the State Department of Education.

For their DNS to support Active Directory it will have to support SRV records. It would also be useful if it supported dynamic registration, otherwise you will have to send them all the DNS changes made by promoting your domain controllers (there should be a file called netlogon.dns in c:\windows\system32\config\ on each of your domain controllers - send all of these files to whoever administers the DNS server).

If you are going to be hosting your own DNS then we need more information about the setup. What DNS domain names are being hosted at the State Department of Education? What domains are in your Active Directory forest?

Edit: To test DNS:

On the machines you are trying to add to the domain, run a `cmd` prompt and then run `nslookup` (nameserver lookup tool). Set the record type to SRV and then query for the list of domain controllers for your domain (replacing "adventure-works.com" with your own domain name). If the query does not return a list of domain controllers and their ip addresses then there is something wrong with DNS somewhere.

```
> set type=srv
> _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.adventure-works.com.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.29.202.90
_kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.adventure-works.com    SRV service location:
      priority       = 0
      weight         = 100
      port           = 88
      svr hostname   = dc1.adventure-works.com
dc1.adventure-works.com internet address = 172.29.202.90
```

Your comment "I couldn't find a good reference to tell me what to put in the blanks when I try to create the record" below is answered by the `netlogon.dns` file I mention above.

Comment: We email them today and they said that we don't need to send them anything, but I'm still unable to add computers to the domain because it says it can't find the DNS name does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve an own domain to an ip address you should need create a forward lookup zone.

I suggest you read this Microsoft Technet article about DNS: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816891(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816891%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Regards

Comment: Well see I tried adding a forward lookup zone but I still couldn't add computers to the domain. I think it was because I didn't have _ldap._tcp.DomainDnsZones records, ForestDnsZones records, etc. Set up. Though I couldn't find a good reference to tell me what to put in the blanks when I try to create the records.